# What i need to change in code to Delete rows with value=0 vba code

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have this VBA code to delete rows where value=0

```
 Sub delete_row()
   Dim linha As Long
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
   With Sheet1
     For linha = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
       If .Cells(linha, "e") = "0000000,00" Then
         .Rows(linha).Delete
       End If
     Next linha
   End With
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

My excel file it's like this:
[image]

However it doesn't run correctly...

Comment: Have you tried `If .Cells(linha, "e") = 0 Then`?

Comment: Then the code run but doesn't delete the rows. I tried these two options:
If .Cells(linha, "e") = "0" Then and
 If .Cells(linha, "e") = "" Then

Comment: Did you try `....entireRow.Delete`?

Comment: Hi! Yes! I found my error! The cells without values had number 0 and some didn't have. So I create a macro with format cells if value>0=value and if cell="";"" and result!